# Send/Receive images via REST

Tags: java, android, web-services, jersey, grizzly

I am using grizzly for java rest service and consuming these web services in an android app.

Its working fine as far as "text" data is concerned.

Now I want to load the images(from server) in my android application, using this rest service and also allow the users to update image from the device.

I have tried this code

```
@GET
@Path("/img3")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getFile()
{
    File file = new File("img/3.jpg");
    return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"") // optional
            .build();
}
```

The code above allow me to download the file, but is it possible to display result in broswer? like this
    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/images/oracle-java-logo.png

Comment: `but is it possible to display result in broswer?`. Well you will have tried i think. So please report.

Comment: @greenapps I am sorry I dont understand what should I report. I am still looking for a solution to display result in browser

Comment: Content disposition should be inline and the media type should be a proper jpeg mime type, not a generic octet stream.

Comment: @Shadow It worked. Thank you so much

Comment: @Shadow What should I do with my question, its on hold?

Comment: You can try the "meta power" and ask why your question has been closed. The rationale given in the closure does not make any sense any longer in my opinion. It only made sense for the initial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution of Part 1:**

I have made the changes in my code as suggested by [Shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389997/shadow)

```
@GET
@Path("/img3")
@Produces("image/jpg")
public Response getFile(@PathParam("id") String id) throws SQLException
{

    File file = new File("img/3.jpg");
    return Response.ok(file, "image/jpg").header("Inline", "filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"")
            .build();
}
```

Requested image will be displayed in browser

**Part 2:**
   The code used to convert back Base64 encoded image

```
@POST
@Path("/upload/{primaryKey}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces("image/jpg")
public String uploadImage(@FormParam("image") String image, @PathParam("primaryKey") String primaryKey) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException
{
    String result = "false";
    FileOutputStream fos;

    fos = new FileOutputStream("img/" + primaryKey + ".jpg");

    // decode Base64 String to image
    try
    {

        byte byteArray[] = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(image);
        fos.write(byteArray);

        result = "true";
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```